# A circle of radius $8$ is inscribed in a right triangle with one base being $20$. What is the hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry

> A circle with a radius of 8 is inscribed in a right triangle with one base being 20. What is the hypotenuse?

Comment: Hey, can you try to show what you have tried to do? Maybe show a picture or some calculations? That way we can help you. :)

Comment: Your question may benefit from a study of [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: You could start by drawing a picture. Then think what you can deduce from the picture. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

[@Daniel Park](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586203/daniel-park), I am giving you a hint. Try to solve these equations
$$
a^2+b^2=c^2\\
r = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a + b - c}\\
$$
where  ***a,  b*** are bases/legs/catheti,

***c*** is the hypotenuse,

and ***r*** is the radius.

More useful information you can find here: [A Right Triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RightTriangle.html)